# How to load a class/module into a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, model

i'm developing an application on Ruby on Rails and i'm stuck. I have a class that maps all the weird characters into a normal characters (i.e. é, è -> e ). I need this class in two models and since i don't want to repeat code, i want to load it so the models can use it. Any idea how to do that?.

**Edit** **I upload the class**

class UtfAnalyzer < Ferret::Analysis::Analyzer
    include Ferret::Analysis

```
CHARACTER_MAPPINGS = {
    ['à','á','â','ã','ä','å','ā','ă']         => 'a',
    ['æ']                                     => 'ae',
    ['ď','đ']                                 => 'd',
    ['ć','č','ĉ','ċ']                         => 'c',
    ['è','é','ê','ë','ē','ę','ě','ĕ','ė',]    => 'e',
    ['ƒ']                                     => 'f',
    ['ĝ','ğ','ġ','ģ']                         => 'g',
    ['ĥ','ħ']                                 => 'h',
    ['ì','ì','í','î','ï','ī','ĩ','ĭ']         => 'i',
    ['į','ı','ĳ','ĵ']                         => 'j',
    ['ķ','ĸ']                                 => 'k',
    ['ł','ľ','ĺ','ļ','ŀ']                     => 'l',
    ['ñ','ń','ň','ņ','ŉ','ŋ']                 => 'n',
    ['ò','ó','ô','õ','ö','ø','ō','ő','ŏ','ŏ'] => 'o',
    ['œ']                                     => 'oek',
    ['ą']                                     => 'q',
    ['ŕ','ř','ŗ']                             => 'r',
    ['ś','š','ş','ŝ','ș']                     => 's',
    ['ť','ţ','ŧ','ț']                         => 't',
    ['ù','ú','û','ü','ū','ů','ű','ŭ','ũ','ų'] => 'u',
    ['ŵ']                                     => 'w',
    ['ý','ÿ','ŷ']                             => 'y',
    ['ž','ż','ź']                             => 'z'
}
HTML_MAPPINGS = {
    ['&agrave;', '&aacute;', '&Agrave;', '&Aacute;', '&auml;', '&Auml;']                => 'a',
    ['&egrave;', '&eacute;', '&Egrave;', '&Eacute;', '&euml;', '&Euml;']                => 'e',
    ['&igrave;', '&iacute;', '&Igrave;', '&Iacute;', '&iuml;', '&Iuml;']                => 'i',
    ['&ograve;', '&oacute;', '&Ograve;', '&Oacute;', '&ouml;', '&Ouml;']                => 'o',
    ['&ugrave;', '&uacute;', '&Ugrave;', '&Uacute;', '&uuml;', '&Uuml;']                => 'u',
    ['&ccedil;', '&Ccedil;']                                                            => 'ç'
}

def self.token_stream(field, str)
  ts = MappingFilter.new(RegExpTokenizer.new(str, /([a-zA-Z0-9ÑñàáäèéëìíïòóöùúüÀÁÈÉËÌÍÏÒÓÖÙÚÜçÇ]|(&([aeiouAEIOU](acute|grave|uml)|ccedil|Ccedil);))+/), HTML_MAPPINGS)
  ts = MappingFilter.new(StandardTokenizer.new(str), CHARACTER_MAPPINGS)
  ts = MappingFilter.new(ts, CHARACTER_MAPPINGS)
  ts = LowerCaseFilter.new(ts)
end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use modules:

```
module CharConverter
  def convert(c)
    #your conversion logic here
  end
end
```

Then include the module in your models:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CharConverter
end
```

The method convert will be available for you in MyModel instance scope (as in `MyModel.new.convert`). In order to make convert available for you in MyModel class scope (as in `MyModel.convert`) replace `include CharConverter` with `extend CharConverter`.

You can find more info on the difference between extend and include [here](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/).

Comment: The problem is that this class extends from Ferret::Analysis::Analyzer, i can't make it into a module (can't i?)

Comment: I see no problem. Take the functionality which is shared out into a module, then include it anywhere you'd like.

Comment: Erez, thanks so much, your solution worked perfect and it's neat and simple. Again, thank you!!